# Run Ansible win_shell without double quotes

Tags: ansible

Below is my script

`win_shell: 'C:\\TEMP\\myscript.ps1 -password {{ password }}'`

But when it executes, it get executed as below and as there is a dollar ($) in password its not working properly.

`"cmd": "C:\\\\TEMP\\\\myscript.ps1 -password abc$efg"`

I want the script to be executed either as

`"cmd": C:\\\\TEMP\\\\myscript.ps1 -password abc$efg,`

or as

`"cmd": 'C:\\\\TEMP\\\\myscript.ps1 -password abc$efg',`

Any hits?

Comment: Possibly you know this, but this is probably very bad form.  It's a good question - escaping strings in ansible is a bit of a chore, but you know that a command like this is going to divulge your password to the users of the OS and possibly be logged, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex_escape filter from Ansible. It will help you escape the special character `$` in your string.

```
win_shell: 'C:\\TEMP\\myscript.ps1 -password {{ password | regex_escape }}'
```

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_escape_filter.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this, I would suggest using win_template and copying the (file with the password in it) to the operating system and running it directly.

Do it in a `block` and shred the file in an `always` section so you can be pretty sure you've trashed that credential when you're done.

Don't copy it to c:\temp either, but copy it to your ansible users's local temp dir so at least it's not necessarily world readable.